# Min of Str Column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column contains a list of values, e.g.

```
dict = {'a' : [0, 1, 2], 'b' : [4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df.loc[:, 'c'] = -1
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.a, x.b], axis=1)
```

So I get:

```
   a  b       c
0  0  4  [0, 4]
1  1  5  [1, 5]
2  2  6  [2, 6]
```

I now would like to save the minimum value of each entry of column c in a new column d, which should give me the following data frame:

```
   a  b       c    d
0  0  4  [0, 4]    0
1  1  5  [1, 5]    1
2  2  6  [2, 6]    2
```

Somehow though I always fail to do it with min() or similar. Right now I am using df.apply(lambda x: min(x['c'], axis=1). But that is too slow in my case. Do you know of a faster way of doing it?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you need column c?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that series (like `df['c']`) are iterable. You can then create a new list and set it as a key, just like you would a dictionary. The list will automatically be cast to a `pd.Series` object. No need to use fancy `pandas` functions unless you are dealing with really (really) big data.

```
df['d'] = [min(c) for c in df['c']]
```

Edit: update to comments below

```
df['d'] = [min(c, key=lambda v: v - df.a) for c in df['c']]
```

This doesn't work because `v` is a value (in the first iteration it is passed `0`, then `4`, for example). `df.a` is a series. `v - df.a` is a new series with the elements `[v - df.a[0], v - df.a[1], ...]`. Then `min` tries to compare these series keys, which doesn't make any sense, because it will be testing `if True, False, ...]` or something like that which `pandas` throws an error for because it doens't really make sense. What you need is

```
df['d'] = [min(c, key=lambda v: v - df['a'][i]) for i, c in enumerate(df['c'])]  
# I prefer to use df['a'] rather than df.a
```

so you take each *value* of `df['a']` in turn from `v`, **not** the entire series `df['a']`.

**However**, taking a constant when calculating the minimum will do absolutely nothing, but I'm guessing this is simplified from what you are actually doing. The two samples above will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Ah right ... this works for a simple case, true! But I have a custom key for sorting, i.e. df.apply(lambda x: min(x['c'], key=lambda v: v[0] - x.a), axis=1) (column a is just on example). But I substract one column here and do other stuff. What works is [min(c, key=lambda v: v[0]) for c in df['c']], but as soon as I do  [min(c, key=lambda v: v[0] - df.a) for c in df['c']] it crashes ..

Comment: Use backtitcks (\`code\`) to present code as `code`. Otherwise that's pretty unreadable. What error are you getting? Can you put what you *actually* want to do in the original question?

Comment: Ok. What I'd like to do is `df['d'] = [min(c, key=lambda v: v - df.a) for c in df['c']]`
(And no I cannot simply substract df.a later, as there is more complex syntax, i.e. an if condition if that is bigger ...). The error I get is "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: OK i've updated my answer to fix the problem but why are you doing that? Taking a constant when testing for the minimum will do absolutely nothing...

Comment: great explanation and answer, thanks a lot! yeah its not a constant I changed the sample so its easier explainable ... I think I have a situation where I need this kind of logic.

Comment: one last (offtopic) question if thats allowed. Similarly I now have been trying to eliminate the apply in `df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x.a, x.b], axis=1)`, so basically I want this column to be a list of several other columns. I tried `df['c'] = [[df['a'][i], df['b'][i]] for i, _ in enumerate(df['a'])]`, but that is pretty slow again, similar to apply. Can I do better?

Comment: `apply` is probably faster because it uses C under the hood. Try `df['c'] = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b'])]` but it may not be fast enough. Python can't make certain assumptions (about independence) that `df.apply` can.

Comment: Ok! Why is the min approach based on your answer then faster than apply? (I measured it)

Comment: Dunno. `lambda` calls can be quite slow (any function called repeatedly tends to be). Try out my solution and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can get help from numpy:

```
import numpy as np 

df['d'] = np.array(df['c'].tolist()).min(axis=1)
```

As stated in the comments, if you don't need the column `c` then:

```
df['d'] = df[['a','b']].min(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a functional solution.

```
df['d'] = list(map(min, df['c']))
```

It works because:

- `df['c']` is a `pd.Series`, which is an iterable object.
- `map` is a lazy operator which applies a function to each element of an iterable.
- Since `map` is lazy, we must apply `list` in order to assign to a series.